# Switching avaudiosession categories then retaking control of remote control center controls

Tags: ios, xcode, controls, avaudiosession

This is my first post asking a question as i never usually need help but i can't figure out if this is even possible. What i need is to switch between these two categories of avaudiosession
and when the switch is made from mixing allowed to no mixing for the app take back control of the remote controls in the control center.

1. [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil]

and

1. [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:nil error:nil]

Ill try explain what is occurring:

They both work independently so if i start with the first avaudiosession config it allows mixing and correctly switches the remote controls in the control center to iPod.

And if i start the second avaudiosession config the app correctly takes control of the remote control in the control center.

The issue occurs when i trying toggle these options. When i toggle the app doesn't retake control of the remote controls after mixing is turned off.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Losing "Now Playing" status from MPRemoteCommandCenter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284272/losing-now-playing-status-from-mpremotecommandcenter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution that works for me, which involves calling

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents]
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents]
```

before setting AVAudioSession category options. eg:

```
NSUInteger options = ... // determine your options

// it seems that calls to beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents and endReceivingRemoteControlEvents
// need to be balanced, so we keep track of the current state in _isReceivingRemoteControlEvents

BOOL shouldBeReceivingRemoteControlEvents = ( 0 == (options & AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers) );

if(_isReceivingRemoteControlEvents != shouldBeReceivingRemoteControlEvents) {
    if(shouldBeReceivingRemoteControlEvents) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
        _isReceivingRemoteControlEvents=YES;
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
        _isReceivingRemoteControlEvents=NO;
    }
}

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:options error:&error];

...

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error]
```

I've been able to achieve consistent results by using a variable to keep track of whether or not the app is currently receiving remote control events so that I can ensure that calls to (begin/end)ReceivingRemoteControlEvents are balanced. I haven't found any documentation that says that you need to do this but otherwise things don't always seem to behave as expected, particularly since I call this code multiple times throughout the course of the application.

In my implementation, the code above gets called each time the app comes to the foreground and also just before each time I begin playing audio.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. I mean if you start with just playback no mixing then run your code it switches to mixing mode (meaning my app is no longer in control of the control center). However if i try to switch back to playback and take control of the control center it doesn't work. Unless there is some other code your using to switch back.

Comment: The key to making this work for me is to call beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents or endReceivingRemoteControlEvents as appropriate immediately prior to  changing the AVAudioSession category options. Did you try doing that? It has also been important to keep track of whether you should be calling begin/end in order to avoid calling begin... while you are already receiving remote control events, or calling end... while you aren't. I hope that makes sense, I tried to explain it in detail in the answer.

Comment: I got it to work and your suggestion was key to making it work. That is keeping track of beginReceiving and endReceiving. However to get working 100% of the time mine needed             
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:nil error:nil]; before creating the session.

Comment: Hi Matthew, could you please elaborate more on your solution? I'm trying to do the same thing but without success. I can go from AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback to AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers with no problem at all. But I can't do the opposite. I mean, as soon as I lose control of the control center to Apple Music, I can't regain it, unless I kill my app.

Comment: I stumbled across this, only to find a similar question which I had solved and answered previously. The answer still works as of the latest iOS 10 beta. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32284816/924021.