# MPRemoteCommandCenter not detecting next track command

Tags: ios, objective-c

I added the following code to `viewDidLoad` trying to track when the next track button is pressed in control center. It's not logging anything though.

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
    [commandCenter.nextTrackCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {
        NSLog(@"next track");
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should begin playing audio. Your app must be the “Now Playing” app. An app does not receive remote control events until it begins playing audio. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html

I've tested on my app that plays video using AVPlayer, all control center buttons(next and prev) work as expected and sending events.

Comment: I put those lines of code after the `[player play];`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the value of commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.enabled property?

Comment: And maybe you need to set AVAudioSession category?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625510/switching-avaudiosession-categories-then-retaking-control-of-remote-control-cent

Comment: I am testing on a device. The value logs enabled. Is there an easier way to set AVAudioSession? I don't know what to put for the options in that link.

Comment: I tried putting in the following code before `MPRemoteCommandCenter` and it still doesn't work: `NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
    NSError *activationErr  = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];`