# Losing "Now Playing" status from MPRemoteCommandCenter

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am creating an application for iOS that can be controlled using the `MPRemoteCommandCenter`. This works fine.

When changing the application  `AVAudioSession` category from `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: .MixWithOthers`, it stops receiving remote control events. This is fine.

But when I change the category back to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`, I do not receive events from `MPRemoteCommandCenter` as expected.

How can I reclaim "Now Playing" status for my application?

Comment: The answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625510/switching-avaudiosession-categories-then-retaking-control-of-remote-control-cent did not help as `beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents` is deprecated in favor of `MPRemoteCommandCenter `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did discover that when setting `AVAudioSessionCategory` the options are retained. So by calling `setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: .MixWithOthers)` first and then `setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)` later, the `.MixWithOthers` option was always in effect.

I was unable to find a `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.None` option, but supplying an empty array did reset the category options.

`.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: [])`